# the package can prompt file path prompt like Bracket while editing HTML

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

It is really handy in **Bracket Editor** that can prompt the file path while typing.

[image]

After search for a while I still cannot find a package that accomplish the same thing Bracket does.

Can you suggest or name one package providing similar feature in **Sublime Text 3**.

Comment: If you're looking for Sublime Text packages, use [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [`AutoFileName`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoFileName), although it can be a bit intrusive at times, if you're trying to type a string literal and it keeps trying to autocomplete paths. Other than that, recent versions seem to work quite well. Another option is [`FileSystem Autocompletion`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileSystem%20Autocompletion), which I haven't tried. [`FuzzyFilePath`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FuzzyFilePath) may also work for you, but only inserts file paths in your current project.